# Angular unit testing Unhandled promise rejection: ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular11

while testing code facing Unhandled promise rejection: ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed.

how can I solve this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this Error is showing me for whole folder sometimes it shows for particular testing 
method and sometimes not so I am not able to understand which code I need to provide. if I get information about why it is occurring because of promise or unsubscribe then I can provide code.